# Dynamically setting domain of a many2many field based on chosen values

Tags: view, odoo, init

I have an app where the user will book deliveries and pick delivery partners for each delivery. I want to prevent the user from picking the same partners for two different deliveries done during the same time.

I want to apply the same method as I do for the on change event but to do it when the view loads.

Here is the method for picking the right domain:

```
def delivery_partners_change(self,cr,uid,ids):
    domain=[]
    print("RECALCULATING DOMAIN")

    # the domain of the delivery partners should be all partners with can_install set that are not present in any conflicting deliveries done during the same time period. 
    for picking in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        print("Picking partners: "+str([x.id for x in picking.delivery_partner_ids]))
        # select partners that are in use by one of the overlapping events
        cr.execute('select id from res_partner where id not in (SELECT r.partner_id FROM stock_picking p, stock_picking_delivery_partner_rel r WHERE ((%s >= p.delivery_date_min and %s < p.delivery_date_max) or (%s <= p.delivery_date_max and %s > p.delivery_date_min)) and r.picking_id = p.id)', (picking.delivery_date_min, picking.delivery_date_min, picking.delivery_date_max, picking.delivery_date_max))
        in_use = cr.fetchall();
        domain = [("id", "in", in_use)]; 
        print("DOMAIN RETURNED = "+str(domain)); 
        return {'domain':{'delivery_partner_ids': domain}}
```

Problem is that when the user opens the view he can see the whole unrestricted domain. He only gets the correct subset of records to choose from after this onchange event fires.

How do I apply this domain to the field at view init, when the user opens the record in the web client?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

In py file,

```
_columns = {

'init_onchange_call': fields.function(delivery_partners_change, string='Nothing Display', help='field at view init', multi="delivery_partners_change"),

}
```

In xml file,

```
<field name="init_onchange_call" invisible="1" />
```

Comment: But then how do I set the domain from the field value func? Currently, the onchange call returns the domain. I can not return the domain from the field func above. I have to set it somehow. How?